# How to fix "#error architecture not supported" when installing pycurl with Python 3.8.2 on macOS 10.15?

Tags: python, macos, pycurl

I am trying to install pycurl 7.44.1 and it fails with a

> #error architecture not supported

message. Here is what I have:

- Python 3.8.2
- libcurl 7.64.1
- macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

---

```
(venv) TestBox:Jet_Testing sz200$ pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.44.1.tar.gz (227 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-wheel-ccs0j7r9
       cwd: /private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/
  Complete output (119 lines):
  Using curl-config (libcurl 7.64.1)
  Warning: libcurl is configured to use SSL, but we have not been able to determine which SSL backend it is using. If your Curl is built against OpenSSL, LibreSSL, BoringSSL, GnuTLS, NSS or mbedTLS please specify the SSL backend manually. For other SSL backends please ignore this message.Not using an SSL library
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/curl
  copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/curl
  running build_ext
  building 'pycurl' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.44.1" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/docstrings.o
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
  #error Unsupported architecture
   ^
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
  typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
  typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
  In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
  In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycurl
  Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
    Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-record-baz5w1vo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/include/site/python3.8/pycurl
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/
    Complete output (121 lines):
    Using curl-config (libcurl 7.64.1)
    Warning: libcurl is configured to use SSL, but we have not been able to determine which SSL backend it is using. If your Curl is built against OpenSSL, LibreSSL, BoringSSL, GnuTLS, NSS or mbedTLS please specify the SSL backend manually. For other SSL backends please ignore this message.Not using an SSL library
    running install
    /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/curl
    copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/curl
    running build_ext
    building 'pycurl' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.44.1" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/docstrings.o
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:
    In file included from src/pycurl.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-install-rksc_p6j/pycurl_bc91e7f44291451db073ce5595b38bf1/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/nf/021t9xld6bg_qcbzxx74v8yh00017w/T/pip-record-baz5w1vo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/sz200/PycharmProjects/Jet_Testing/venv/include/site/python3.8/pycurl Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any idea what might be causing this?  I've tried also installing with easy_install, and it looks like it had gone much smoother, but after trying to import it will still error out as if it had not been installed.

Update: Installing with the following flag seems to get passed the unsupported architecture issues:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl
```

However, upon trying to import/run in Python it still fails with an openssl issue:

```
    Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (secure-transport, openssl) do not include compile-time ssl backend (none/other)
```

Comment: Are you on an M1 Mac?

Comment: @TimRoberts How can I tell?  MacBook Pro, intel Core i7

Comment: Python 3.8.2? Are you using the default, built-in Python provided by macOS? Or did you install from a separate one (ex. from Python.org, from Homebrew, etc.)? I can't reproduce on my mac (not on M1 mac though), but I regularly had similar "unsupported architecture" problems before using the built-in Python 3.8.2.

Comment: It might help to add the output of `clang -v` (as part of `pip install`, it is compiling the C libs part of pycurl).

Comment: @TimRoberts No, *obviously* not. M1 Macs cannot run 10.15.

Comment: As you can see from the clang command being printed, the build system is trying to build for both Intel and ARM (`-arch arm64 -arch x86_64`). You can't do that with the 10.15 SDK. You'll need to figure out how to build for Intel only (you could build for Intel and ARM with the macOS 11 SDK but the resulting binary might not work on 10.15).

Comment: I hate to add to this convo in the comments.  But adding 'ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install pycurl' does help install and finish.  However, upon an "import pycurl" in python I now get: ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (secure-transport, openssl) do not include compile-time ssl backend (none/other).  Which seems like a whole other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have fixed the unsupported architecture and openssl issue now:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know if `ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64 -arch arm64e -arch x86_64"` creates a universal binary.

Answer (score 1):

Recently (July 2023) ran into this issue too, with the following setup for my Intel Macbook.

- VS Code 1.79.2
- Python 3.10.5 venv
- pycurl 7.45.2
- macOS Ventura 13.4.1
- openssl 3.1

I solved my issues with help from the other comments and adding ALL of the following lines to my bash_profile

```
# Settings for Pycurl
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1/lib/pkgconfig"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@3.1/bin:${PATH}"
export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Comment: I tried various things and this solution actually solved my issue.