# How do I fix the jsonobject architecture problem I am having in PyCharm CE when the terminal says the package is installed?

Tags: python, pycharm, x86-64

How do I get `jsonobject` to install even though, apparently, my terminal thinks is already installed?

I am trying to work through the a Python project that I have copied to a repo and cloned from [the open-source code in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/InstituteforDiseaseModeling/synthpops)

I am using PyCharm CE (Build #PC-233.15026.15, built on March 21, 2024, Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1087.23 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.)

Python version is 3.11

My Mac OS is: Monterey version 12.7.4 This is a Mac from 2013 so has the Intel infrastructure.

I have managed to install all dependences apart from `jsonobject`.

My terminal seems to think that `jsonobject` has been installed:

```
(base) [name here] ~ % ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install jsonobject
Requirement already satisfied: jsonobject in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from jsonobject) (1.16.0)
```

The content of that folder is
[image: Content of json folder]

It is not, however, showing in the Python Interpreter list:
[image: List of package things in the Python Interpreter, no jsonobject]

But I still get this error inside PyCharm ([MY FILE PATH HERE] is substituting for the local path to the folder):

```
 [MY FILE PATH HERE]/SynthPops/.venv/bin/python 
 [MY FILE PATH HERE]/SynthPops/examples/ex01_make_dhaka_city.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "[MY FILE PATH HERE]/SynthPops/examples/ex01_make_dhaka_city.py", line 6, in <module>
import synthpops as sp
File "[MY FILE PATH HERE]/SynthPops/synthpops/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .data import *  # depends on defaults, config
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "[MY FILE PATH HERE]/SynthPops/synthpops/data.py", line 5, in <module>
from jsonobject import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jsonobject'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When trying to install `jsonobject` from inside `PyCharm` I received the same `unsupported architecture` errors as shown in questions such as [pycurl architecture problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074054/how-to-fix-error-architecture-not-supported-when-installing-pycurl-with-pytho) and [psutil architecture problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111015/pip-install-psutil-is-throwing-error-unsupported-architecture-any-workarou). The solution in both was to run

```
 ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install [name]
```

which, in my case, is `jsonobject`. That line still failed inside `PyCharm` although it appeared to work in the terminal.

Comment: Did you try `python -m pip install jsonobject`?

Comment: I got the same terminal message that it was installed. Still not being found inside PyCharm. Same error as I posted. :(